# What is the rate limit for Google App Script Web App doGet/doPost calls?

Tags: google-apps-script

As the page for quotas
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas does not really describe anything meant for web apps.

What is the rate limit or quota when calling custom API deployed as app web  exposed to the public in app script? How it will respond to abuse like spams or DDOS?

Comment: It depends on what your API is doing. What are you connecting to on the back-end of your API?

Comment: It's connected to google sheets, only read actions.

Comment: I wouldn't worry so much about the quota compared with you many rows you will have in your sheets. Once you hit 50,000 - 60,000 rows although the sheets will work they become ever increasingly difficult to handle. There are ways to project against spam and DDOS, and I think google also have built in methods.

Comment: Do you have an answer yet, @Cerlancism?

Comment: @Tran Dinh Khanh No. But a good guess is to go by Simultaneous executions